# Change Navigator in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an Android app with two logical parts: Login screens and main app screens.
Login screens (login, registration, restore password etc) are packed in `StackNavigator` and are working rather well. But after login app needs to use `DrawerNavigator` without possibility to go back to login screen with system Back button.

Some googling showed that it is possible to place `DrawerNavigator` as a screen inside `StackNavigator` and to prevent going back using  `BackHandler.addEventListener`

But I'd prefer to completely remove `StackNavigator` after login and to replace it with `DrawerNavigator` without nesting. And vice versa, after user logs off, to replace `DrawerNavigator` with a `StackNavigator`. Is it possible? Or maybe nesting should be used in this case?

**Edit**
Thanks to @AshwinMothilal - correct tool is SwitchNavigator, full description of the process can be found [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

Comment: Have you tried Switch Navigator which is designed for this purpose

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Not yet, thanks for advice.